# Using simple_list_item_activated_2 in Android App

Tags: java, android

First off I'm new with Java so bear with me. I am working on modifying the master detail template to list 2 lines from a dummy content file (this will later pull from shared prefs) and am not quite sure how to pull this off.

My Dummy Content class is this:

```
package com.fasttracksites.skyrimjournal.data;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class JournalEntries {

    /**
     * An array of sample (dummy) items.
     */
    public static List<JournalEntry> ITEMS = new ArrayList<JournalEntry>();

    /**
     * A map of sample (dummy) items, by ID.
     */
    public static Map<String, JournalEntry> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, JournalEntry>();

    static {
        // Add 3 sample items.
        addItem(new JournalEntry("1", "08-30-1995", "Item 1", "Item 1 Details"));
        addItem(new JournalEntry("2", "08-30-1998", "Item 2", "Item 2 Details"));
        addItem(new JournalEntry("3", "08-30-2013", "Item 3", "Item 3 Details"));
    }

    private static void addItem(JournalEntry item) {
        ITEMS.add(item);
        ITEM_MAP.put(item.mId, item);
    }

    /**
     * A dummy item representing a piece of content.
     */
    public static class JournalEntry {
        public String mId;
        public String mDate;
        public String mTitle;
        public String mContent;

        public JournalEntry(String id, String date, String title, String content) {
            mId = id;
            mDate = date;
            mTitle = title;
            mContent = content;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return mContent;
        }
    }
}
```

It is instantiated in EntryListActivity like so:

```
protected static ArrayList<JournalEntry> mJournalEntries = new ArrayList<JournalEntry>();
```

This is then being attached to the List in EntryListFragment (which is where I'm having trouble at) like so:

```
String[] keys = { JournalEntries.ITEMS }
        int[] ids = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), EntryListActivity.mJournalEntries,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_2,
                keys, ids);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

How do I properly attach the Dummy Content so that **JournalEntry.mTitle** is the first line and **JournalEntry.mDate** is the second line?

Answer (score 1):

Its not the greatest solution but here's what I did to fix this. The issue results from the fact that SimpleAdapter is wanting a map of String,String. Since the default dummy data class, in this case JournalEntries, uses String,JournalEntry we have to change it up a little bit.

First we need to track the String,String values so we add a new variable that will store this within our class like so:

```
    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mJournalEntries = 
            new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

New we need to modify the addItem method to store info into this list so we do this using the following code:

```
        HashMap<String, String> journalEntry = new HashMap<String, String>();
        journalEntry.put(KEY_DATE, item.mDate);
        journalEntry.put(KEY_TITLE, item.mTitle);

        mJournalEntries.add(journalEntry);
```

What this does is create a temporary HashMap that is then added to our temporary variable and this is finally added to our new variable. We are using constants for the keys so that we can refrence this elsewhere and change it from a single location.

Next we need to fix our main code by referencing the proper String,String map.

```
String[] keys = { JournalEntries.KEY_TITLE, JournalEntries.KEY_DATE };
        int[] ids = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), JournalEntries.mJournalEntries, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, keys, ids);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

This creates a new 2 line SimpleAdapter that has our Title on the first line and the date on the second line. We are referencing the variables from our class so that we don't have to duplicate the variables in each class that references the data.

Final Dummy Data Class

```
package com.fasttracksites.skyrimjournal.data;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class JournalEntries {

    /**
     * An array of sample (dummy) items.
     */
    public static List<JournalEntry> ITEMS = new ArrayList<JournalEntry>();

    /**
     * A map of sample (dummy) items, by ID.
     */
    public final static String KEY_DATE = "date";
    public final static String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static Map<String, JournalEntry> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, JournalEntry>();
    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mJournalEntries = 
            new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    static {
        // Add 3 sample items.
        addItem(new JournalEntry("1", "08-30-1995", "Item 1", "Item 1 Details"));
        addItem(new JournalEntry("2", "08-30-1998", "Item 2", "Item 2 Details"));
        addItem(new JournalEntry("3", "08-30-2013", "Item 3", "Item 3 Details"));
    }

    private static void addItem(JournalEntry item) {
        ITEMS.add(item);
        ITEM_MAP.put(item.mId, item);

        HashMap<String, String> journalEntry = new HashMap<String, String>();
        journalEntry.put(KEY_DATE, item.mDate);
        journalEntry.put(KEY_TITLE, item.mTitle);

        mJournalEntries.add(journalEntry);
    }

    /**
     * A dummy item representing a piece of content.
     */
    public static class JournalEntry {
        public String mId;
        public String mDate;
        public String mTitle;
        public String mContent;

        public JournalEntry(String id, String date, String title, String content) {
            mId = id;
            mDate = date;
            mTitle = title;
            mContent = content;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return mContent;
        }
    }
}
```